# How to handle this workplace harassment?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior, australia, sexual-harassment

I am asking on behalf of my colleague. She started working with this company four years back. She is the finance manager. From day one she faced sexual harrasment from her boss.

Little history, She had her own business before joining here. She is registered tax accountant and had her own tax/bookkeeping company. Due to her son she quit the business and started working here as finance manager.

When she started it was all good for her. But after a while my boss started to harras her (Wanted to have sexual relations). Its been 2 years she denied it.
There is another reason boss know she is going through tough times because her son is autistic and there are court cases too with her previous partner.

This makes her easier target. All that my boss knows and using this info to abuse her every day. He abuse her every day and try to make sure that she some how stays late in office.

Today she resigned my boss is not here he is spending his holidays in hawaii so he said that he will have meeting with her after holidays.

How to deal with him upon his return from holidays because he use to abuse her without any reason. But now he got the reason ?

She is getting anxiety just by thinking of him coming back to office for final exit interview. How to deal with that interview ?

Also there is huge possibility of getting  raised and  abusing continues.

Comment: Between the title question and the final one, there is quite some difference, could you choose one of them ? Or do you want to know how to handle the final exit interview and handle the notice period ?

Comment: She doesn't need to attend her exit interview. Many people decline to do so. Ideally, she should consult a lawyer on sexual harassment. She shouldn't subject herself to this kind of environment.

Comment: @TomTom You could edit the question instead.

Comment: @TomTom Not everyone who visits this site speaks English as their first language. Please remember our [Be Nice policy](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). As Masked Man said, if you feel you can improve a question, then you are welcome to [edit] it yourself.

Comment: If your office has an HR, she should go to them tell them why she is resigning and ask them to prevent her from meeting with this person alone.

Answer (score 2):

Just send an email: “I am sorry, but my lawyer strongly suggested that I should not attend any meetings with you without him present”. He might then think about how his actions could be construed as constructive dismissal.

Comment: Actually he may just fire. Refusal to work as contracted, finished. Dismissal with cause.

Comment: What are you going on about? She put in her resignation.

Comment: And if the harasser tries to fire you, that’s when your lawyer says “that will be fun”.